# How to receive http response data use socket?

Tags: python, networking, protocol-buffers, recv

As you know sometimes we can't know what the size of the data(if there is no `Content-Length` in http response header).

What is the best way to receive http response data(use socket)?

The follow code can get all the data but it will blocking at `buf = sock.recv(1024)`.

```
from socket import *
import sys

sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect(('www.google.com', 80))
index = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHOST:www.google.com\r\nConnection:keep-alive\r\n\r\n"
bdsock.send(index)

data = ""
while True:
    buf = bdsock.recv(1024)
    if not len(buf):
        break
    data += buf
```

Comment: If you're also writing the sender code, use a header system. Otherwise you can loop recv() until it returns an empty string (might be None but who cares they're both Falsey).

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are writing the sender as well.

A classic approach is to prefix any data sent over the wire with the length of the data. On the receive side, you just greedily append all data received to a buffer, then iterate over the buffer each time new data is received.

So if I send 100 bytes of data, I would prefix an int 100 to the beginning of the packet, and then transmit. Then, the receiver knows exactly what it is looking for. IF you want to get fancy, you can use a special endline sequence like `\x00\x01\x02` to indicate the proper end of packet. This is an easily implemented form of error checking.

Comment: I'm not writing the sender and I use http protocol. Some website return has no `Content-Length` attribute and there is no a special endline sequence.

Answer (score -1):

Use a bigger size first, do a couple of tests, then see what is the lenght of those buffers, you will then have an idea about what would the maximum size be. Then just use that number +100 or so just to be sure.
Testing different scenarios will be your best bet on finding your ideal buf size.
It would also help to know what protocol you are using the sockets for, then we would have a better idea and response for you.

Comment: It is http protocol, what I should set buf size?

Answer (score -1):

Today I got the same question again. 
And I found the simple way is use [httplib](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/httplib.html?highlight=httplib#httplib.HTTPResponse).

```
r = HTTPResponse(sock)
r.begin()
# now you can use HTTPResponse method to get what you want.
print r.read()
```

Comment: Actually this not answer the question. The answer is what HTTPResponse did.